# Xamarin, return WCF data to PCL from specific platform libraries

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin

I'm working on a client/server project but struggling to make it work, mostly because `System.ServiceModel` cannot be accessed in PCL.

But that's OK, I managed to use `DependencyServices` that I call from PCL to manage the connection with the server from each specific platform.

My problem is, once I call for example

```
var result = DependencyService.Get<Interface>().Operation(param);
```

this will go to the platform specific, there I'm doing the binding, endpoint and calling the real operation from WCF, that is Async, so from now I cannot return the result from WFC in this method, because this will be returned to another method once the operation is completed.

My goal is to do most of the job on PCL so I don't have to start writing my interface multiple times for each platform. So in resume what I need is a way to return result from server (WCF, or some other that would make it work) in my PCL.

Comment: You can use another interface and dependency injection to do that. BTW, I use all WCF calls in PCL, not sure why it doesn't work for you. Are you using XForms or Classic?

Comment: If the function you are calling is async the result will be returned to the same caller if you await. What is the problem? Can you share a little more code of functions definitions and calls?

Comment: @YuriS I'm using XForms. When I put my service.cs in MyApp(Portable), I receive errors like _The type or namespace name '...' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ServiceModel' ..._. It works normally if i put it on the MyApp.Droid project, so I assumed it woudn't work in the PCL. Hope you have a work around this.

Comment: I tried it on forms and it worked. How do you generate your proxy? I use VS and it works

Comment: @YuriS There is not a lot of code to share, I just created a simple Xamarin project and I'm trying to manage a simple connection between the app and the server. I followed the [Xamarin tutorials](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/) to create the WCF and it was fine until it started working with plataform specific, what I do not want.

Comment: For what I can assume, using _Silverlight Service Model Proxy Generation Tool (SLsvcUtil.exe)_ to generate my proxy is forcing me to use _System.ServiceModule_. If there are other methods to get a proxy, which one do you use to make it work ? thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126976/discussion-between-user2136984-and-yuri-s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create WCF proxy/client in PCL using VS and avoid all these problems

[image]

If Service Reference is not available in your options check library settings

[image]

Comment: Service reference only shows up when you don't have windows phone 8.1 selected

Comment: so, the way I was doing with silverlight generating proxy works too, BUT you cannot target Windows phone since if i do it doesn't let me use System.ServeModel

Comment: silverlight generating proxy works too in portable library. it is a little more work but doable. I only care about windows phone 8.0 so service reference works for me